# Add Headers to Table control and retrieving data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use Table control from ToolBox and retrieve data from database. My code is working but when I try to add a header to the table, I can not get the header correctly at its place.

My Code:

```
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable()`;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "select ........   ";
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(tbl);
    // Current row count.
    int rowCtr;
    // Total number of cells per row (columns).
    int cellCtr;
    // Current cell counter
    int cellCnt;
    cellCnt = 2;

for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= num; rowCtr++)
{
    // Create new row and add it to the table.

    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
    Label lbl = new Label();

    for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
    {
        TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

        if (cellCtr == 1)
        {
            lbl.ID = "lblData" + cellCtr;
            lbl.Text = ds.Tables["MyTableName"].Rows[rowCtr - 1][cellCtr - 1].ToString();
            tCell.Text = lbl.Text;
        }
        else if (cellCtr == 2)
        {
            tbx.ID = "txtData" + cellCtr;
            tbx.Enabled = true;
            tbx.Text = ds.Tables["MyTableName"].Rows[rowCtr - 1][cellCtr - 1].ToString();
            tCell.Text = tbx.Text;
        }
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: i don't see TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow(); // Creating a header row any where or i am missing something?

Comment: I delete it because it was wrong

Comment: Any reason to not use GridView or ListView?

Comment: Wrong mean Header was not Showing up or it was throwing error ? Did you add 'header' to the table like tbl.Rows.Add(header);?

Comment: I want to learn how to use table tool and I did not think about GridView or ListView.

Comment: I use: TableHeaderCell h = new TableHeaderCell();
            h.Text = "Cell";
            tRow.Cells.Add(h);  
in the outer for loop

Comment: tRow is table row, you want to add header to table not to Table row..

Comment: and also i am not sure how you are saying code is working fine because you are filling data table not data set but you are getting data from data set, Or you have missed to mention some part of code?

Comment: Yes it is working fine only the headers problem. There was a wrong part of code and this is the correct missed code : adp.Fill(ds, "MyTableName");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88069/discussion-between-angloos-and-rose).

Comment: Worth mentioning. Table is not a tool, it's a control.